# High Speed Capture Session Image Reader

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera2

I'm trying to use the camera2 api to get image data as often as possible and then process it using opencv. High Speed Capture Session should allow higher fps, but I'm couldn't find any resources to access the image data and honestly much information on High Speed Capture Session. Any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the data from a constrained high speed capture session; it only sends high-speed data to the video encoder; the preview output only receives 30fps.

This is because the high-speed mode on both devices uses too many resources to support other outputs.  Any device that does have enough resources can just expose a 240 / 120 fps option in regular aeTargetFpsRanges, and then you can use the API as usual.  But I'm not aware of any devices that can do this.

Comment: So there is no way to do image processing at high fps?

Comment: The APIs allow it if a device can support it, but I'm not aware of any devices that list >= 120fps rates in their normal frame duration options.